# Literally can't figure out a way to increase Touchpad Speed beyond windows maximum

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad

I've downloaded a dozen softwares for "mouse speed increase" but none of them work for laptop touchpads, even `Mouse Speed Switcher`, have tried registry hacks, etc, nothing works.

What can I do to increase the "DPI" of my touchpad beyond the maximum slider in Options? I'm curious for a solution that works on any windows computer brand.

TL;DR I want my cursor to move faster with less distance traveled of my finger on the touchpad.

Comment: Look at the [registry](https://www.alphr.com/how-to-adjust-mouse-sensitivity-in-windows-10/) method (down on the page).  Your mileage will vary.  It will allow you to put in values that the dialog will not.

Comment: Upgrade your OS? Otherwise yeah, registry hack is all that comes to mind. You probably want to roll back to the backup you made before installing a dozen different things. vindows can't uninstall things properly so now you have a dozen other things complicating the issue.

Comment: Usually you use mouse accelleration such that if you swipe fast, the cursor flies across the screen. The cursor becomes less precise but is better to be used. Sometimes this setting is called precise

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas need actual solution / specific example if you can provide an "answer" below. have tried reg edits before that did not work

Comment: @mitts need actual solution / specific example if you can provide an "answer" below. , have tried reg edits before that did not work

Comment: @LPChip unfortunately this is a very basic response and I have powerhoused through dozens of advanced options and returned no result. This is quite simply put an unsolved question on pretty much all of the internet as far as I can tell. You'd think something like this would be very easy / already done but I cannot find any working reg edits or programs to actually accomplish this.

Comment: `have tried reg edits before` doesn't explain WHAT you did.  One "reg edit" is not another.  I bet the comment I provided will work.  If it doesn't, nothing but a new driver or new hardware will.

Comment: "Upgrade your OS" was the actual solution.

Comment: @mitts then put it as "answer" if you think that is actually going to cut it for SU standards

Comment: Good luck bro..

Comment: @mitts good luck breaking 100 rep bro